# Change jupyter notebook markdown font color in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using VScode with a dark theme and the text dispayed in Jupyter notebook markdown is pretty pale [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Sdh.png)

What I have been doing is trying to change my color theme in `settings.json`,  but I can not find a variable that accounts for the notebook markup font color, let me give you an example of an existing variable that is similar to what I am looking for `"notebook.markup.fontSize": 20`. I could not find neither the variable nor the full list of such.

I know I might explicitly assing font color for each cell, but I find it really tedious as I have tons of them.

Are there any other solutions to this problem?

I have tried installing extensions, checking out jupyter VScode settings. Couldn't find anything.

Comment: I also face this kind of problem. It seems like the **Jupyter Notebook in VSCode** does not provide that feature.

Answer (score 1):

it's depended on the `foreground` setting.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "foreground": "#f1f1f1"
}
```